# Significato di "picchio" in questo contesto

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Diceria dell'untore*, di Gesualdo Bufalino, ho letto:

> Solo mi ritrovai sul marciapiedi, quando fui sceso dal convoglio in sosta, e solo m’incamminai verso casa, sempre più certo a mano a mano che, se anche arrivavo senza preavviso e dal mio espatrio tanto tempo era trascorso, mille nemici vi erano, scaltri, svegli, feroci, che mi
>   aspettavano al varco. Sicuro, mille e mille ricordi mi facevano la posta, in veste di mendicanti o sicari, né c’era verso di liberarsene. Davanti all’uscio dal noto colore, mentre la mia mano esitava, tenendo a mezz’aria un **picchio di ferro** imbrunito dal tempo, eccoli, prima l’uno, poi l’altro, poi tutti insieme: strabocchevole ciurma, le cui voci, insultando, supplicando, mi si rincorrevano nelle orecchie, sperando in una risposta che non sapevo
>   trovare.

Potreste spiegarmi cos'è questo "picchio di ferro" che appare in questo brano?
Ho cercato il termine "picchio" in parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato nulla che possa essere di ferro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il ***picchio di ferro*** altro non è che un modo non comune di chiamare il [batacchio](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/batacchio) da porta utilizzato appunto per bussare picchiando sul portone di casa.

> **batàcchio** s. m. [lat. ✻batuacŭlum, ✻*battaclum*, der. di *batt(u)ĕre*
>   «battere»]. – 1. Bastone o pertica per bacchiare. 2. Battaglio della
>   campana o, meno com., dell’uscio.

E più esplicitamente sul sinonimi e contrari di Treccani per [batacchio](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/batacchio_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/):

> **batacchio** /ba'tak:jo/ s. m. [lat. ✻batuacŭlum, ✻battaclum, der. di
>   batt(u)ĕre "battere"]. - 1. [bastone per bacchiare] ≈ asta, bacchio,
>   batocchio, clava, legno, mazza, pertica, randello, stanga, stecca,
>   verga. 2. a. [elemento metallico posto all'interno della campana che
>   la fa suonare] ≈ batocchio, battaglio, (*non com.*) battocchio. b.
>   [**arnese che serve a picchiare sulla porta o sul portone di casa**] ≈
>   batocchio, battaglio, battente, battiporta, (*non com.*) battocchio,
>   martello, (*region.*) mazzapicchio, (*non com.*) **picchio**, (*non com.*)
>   picchiotto.